# How to convert .wav to formula?

Tags: fft, wav, scilab

In scilab I can write like:

```
    t=soundsec(0.5);
    s=[sin(2*%pi*440*t)];
    savewave('foo.wav', s);
```

and by this convert formula to .wav.

But how can I convert .wav to formula? If I use

```
    analyze(loadwave('foo.wav'));
```

I only got graphic? What to do?

Comment: You mean you want to analyze a soundwave and get, say, ``sin(880*pi*t)`` as result? That is a not a trivial task, and you first need to understand Fourier Series.

Comment: Yes, I mean it. If I use fft(loadwave('foo.wav')); then I got some coeffs. What to do next?